# Error in installation directory

Tags: installation, sudo, directory, make

I'm trying to install my first linux package... what an oddysey.

After finding out what `sudo` is and sense what `make file` does, and losing a lot of time on the internet, I'm about to quit... Hopefully I can get some help here.

1. Untar
2. Change to uncompressed folder and search furiously to find out how to install things in linux
3. Download `g++`; I don't know why it no longer comes with the distro :(.
4. Read `readme`
5. Open a console (Ubuntu! a direct access to the console!) and type

   ```
   make dep
   ```
6. Type on the console

   ```
   make
   ```
7. Type on the console

   ```
   make install
   ```

   ----> error (Superuser? this is like Windows Vista -- not to desperate)
8. Type on the console

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```

   ----> error

   ```
   covrita@covrita-Lenovo-B580:/media/covrita/UBUNTU/nueva2/picprog-1.9.1$ sudo make install
   [sudo] password for covrita: 
   install -c -o 0 -g 0 -m 755 picprog /usr/local/bin/
   install -c -o 0 -g 0 -m 644 *.1 /usr/local/man/man1/
   install: el objetivo «/usr/local/man/man1/» no es un directorio: No existe el archivo o el directorio
   make: *** [install] Error 1
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! This is an english-only site so you will have to modify your question from spanish to english. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Por favor, al menos hacé el intento de usar un traductor robótico (por ejemplo, [el perevodchik de Prompt](http://www.online-translator.com/Default.aspx?prmtlang=es) o el de Google, o el que sea), y poné tu pregunta en español, pero también la traducción, por mala que sea, en inglés. Aquí con gusto la corregirán los que hablan bien el idioma. En todo caso, las respuestas las recibirás en inglés.

Comment: I have Google Translated it, it should be up in a minute.

Comment: @Ivan, please add more information about the package you want to install: where did you get it, what instructions you got, if you looked for it in the Software Center, etc. Por favor editá tu pregunta y ponenos dónde conseguiste el programa, qué instrucciones trae, si es que no existe en el Centro de Software,y cualquier otra información útil.

Comment: @carnendil Please don't continue in Spanish (next to English).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to install 'picprog'. This is available as a Ubuntu package in the official repositories. No need to install from source! Click the button below and you should be set in a few seconds.

[image: Install via the software center]